# How can I set the default search engine for Firefox without the GUI on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, automation, setup, search-engines

I want to automate the setup of Firefox on Linux, to harden it and change the default search engine. You can almost edit all configuration options via the user.js file, but not the default search engine setting.

Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the default search engine is too malware prone and cant be accomplished except through group policies in Windows, or for Linux through something called Enterprise Policy Engine which is available for Firefox.

This works through an addon called [Enterprise Policy Generator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enterprise-policy-generator/) and the use of a [`policies.json`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson) file. Both links will set you on your way to make use of the enterprise policy engine.

In your `policies.json` file, the following lines allow you to define the default search engine:

```json
{
  "policies": {
    "SearchEngines": {
      "Default": "NAME_OF_SEARCH_ENGINE"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Firefox but could this be done with about:config as an automated install process? Or are you already using about:config and this answer is completely redundant?  :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer is exceedingly clear to anyone familiar with the topic.